# Why aren't my files being uploaded to Firestore not uploading in order?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am currently trying to make an Image Uploader using Vue 2, Vuetify and Firebase/Firestore. At the moment, my images upload successfully to Firestore and the reference download URL is stored in an array called "images" but they are not stored in order like they appear so on my frontend.

This is currently how the frontend looks like with files selected to be uploaded:

[image: files selected on frontend]

When pressing Submit Presentation, I have it print the files in the console: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHN81.png

[image: files in console]

As you can see, they print in order, but another issue that arises is that the images don't get to sent to the Firebase database, but they still get uploaded to Firestore. For it to show up in the Firebase database, I would have to press the Submit Presentation button again or else the array in Firebase will just show up as images: []. This is a whole other issue I assume but it might help with figuring out the main issue.

When I press Submit Presentation again, the images array gets updated with each download URL, but not in order:

[image: images array from Firebase]

It says Slide1 then Slide3, Slide12, Slide9, etc. I have no idea why this is happening. Even in Firestore, they are not in order. It's a complete different order from the one in the Firebase database.

[image: Firestore]

Here is how I handle the file uploading when the Submit Presentation button is pressed:

```
    uploadImages() {
      if (this.files) {
        this.files.forEach(file => {
          var storageRef = fb.storage().ref('presentations/' + file.name);
          //storageRef.put(file);

          let uploadTask = storageRef.put(file);

          uploadTask.on('state_changed', (snapshot) => {

          }, (error) => {
            //Errors handled her
          }, () => {
            uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadURL) => {
              this.presentation.images.push(downloadURL);
            })
          })
          console.log(file);
          db.collection("presentations").doc("mainPresentation").update(this.presentation)
        })
      }
    }
```

I just want the images to be stored in order like how they are selected, because as you probably noticed, these are presentation images, so when I have to read from Firebase, I don't want the presentation images being displayed in a different order.

Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

Firstly, you are kicking off all these uploads asynchronously, simultaneously.  Since they are all happening at the same time, they could finish in a different order.  If you need them to happen in order, then you should wait for the first one to complete before kicking off the second one.  I suggest not worrying about it, and sort the data afterward as needed.

Also, the sort order of the file that you see in the Cloud Storage console is lexicographic, not numeric.  Lexicographically, "11" comes before "2", because the ascii value for the first character "1" is less than "2".  If you really want to see the files sorted numerically, you should pad the numbers with zeroes so that the lexical sort matches the numeric sort.  For example, "001", "002", "003" and so on.

Comment: The second half of your answer is really what's going on here.

Comment: @Stuart The second half only explains the Cloud Storage console sort ordering.  In the database screenshot, the ordering of the final array is different, and that would be explained by out-of-order uploads.

Comment: How would I go upon sorting the data afterwards? I assume this would have to be done via Firebase and not on the frontend. Can confirm the padding numbers with the zeroes works, but of course that it only helps with it being viewed on the Cloud Storage console and not it being sorted with the Firebase database.

Comment: Instead of just pushing everything into an array, make a separate document for each file, attach a number field to those documents, and order your query by that number.  Basically, you will have to invent some way to identify the order you desire.  It's not going to happen automatically unless you also force the upload order.

Comment: Isn't that a lot more inconvenient, having to make a document for each file? When you say documents, I am referring to where the mainPresentation doc is shown in this picture: https://i.imgur.com/3f3JeZT.png

Comment: Choose whatever method you want to sort your information.

Comment: Hmm alright, this is all new to me so apologies about the many questions. Still confused on how to achieve this, but I think I'll figure it out!